# how to save all tpr fpr data points of ROC into dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, roc

i want to save all fpr and tpr points for ROC in df and then save that df into csv

```
import sklearn.metrics as metrics
# calculate the fpr and tpr for all thresholds of the classification

fpr, tpr, threshold = metrics.roc_curve(y_true1, y_pred1)
roc_auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)

# method I: plt

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, 'b', label = 'AUC = %0.2f' % roc_auc)
plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1],'r--')
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([0, 1])
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.show()
```

I tried this .. Is this a correct way??

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.DataFrame(tpr).to_csv("C:/ROC.csv")
pd.DataFrame(fpr).to_csv("C:/ROC1.csv")
```

Comment: It looks correct. Are the csv files as you expected?

Comment: yeah its giving only 4 data points for tpr but why tpr should have only 4 datapoints .. and if I save both tpr and for in same csv file then tpr first point is missing

Comment: What do fpr and tpr look like? Print them before saving them as csv.